# PyQt4 Threading: Sending data back to a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, signals, pyqt4

I'm writing a program, with a PyQt frontend.  To ensure that the UI doesn't freeze up, I use QThreads to emit signals back to the parent.  Now, I have reached a point where I need my thread to stop running, emit a signal back to the parent, then wait on the parent to return an approval for the thread to continue (after the user interacts with the UI a little bit).

I've been looking into the [QMutex](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmutex.html) class, along with [QThread's wait](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qthread.html#wait) function.

How should I go about doing this properly?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is using a [condition variable](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwaitcondition.html).

In my code, however, I prefer using Python's built-in `Queue` objects to synchronize data between threads. While I'm at it, I use Python's threads as opposed to PyQt threads, mainly because it allows me to reuse the non-GUI part of the code without an actual GUI.